# What would be the better way to have Authorization with play using JAVA and CAS

Tags: java, authorization, cas, playframework-2.2

I'd like to know which mechanism I should use to implement authorization once I must use Central Authentication Server and it'll be written using Java. Is there any that was made thinking about cas module?

Another way would be use pac4j and Deadbolt2 at the same time, so, is that the best way so on?
Btw, I took a look at Deadbolt2 but i'm not sure if it fits well for play 2.2 version, does it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the creator of `pac4j` and I don't know `deadbolt2`. Reading quickly the doc, it seems a bit complicated at first glance.
I had in mind to create something really easy (maybe too simple?) for authorizations in `play-pac4j`: get the roles from the attributes of the user profile and add a *rolesRequired* attribute in the `@RequiresAuthentication`... Would you mind opening an issue on the `play-pac4j` project on Github to continue this discussion? Thx

Comment: pac4j v1.8 now has an Authorizer concept: https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/master/pac4j-core/src/main/java/org/pac4j/core/authorization/Authorizer.java. It will be integrated in the future versions of play-pac4j.

Comment: I am using play 2.4 and building an application where I need to do ldap authentication and authorization. Looking at so many security modules, I found pac4J really interesting as it fits my requirement but the problem I am facing is insufficient information provided in website. I am looking for a documentation highlighting steps or sample code with steps which I can refer to do basic setup for ldap authentication. I am using Java technology. Can you please provide me link or document for this. Thanks !!

Comment: LDAP authentication is supported via the LdapAuthenticator: https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/master/pac4j-ldap/src/main/java/org/pac4j/ldap/credentials/authenticator/LdapAuthenticator.java whose configuration relies on a Ldaptive Authenticator (http://www.ldaptive.org/). Example: https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/master/pac4j-ldap/src/test/java/org/pac4j/ldap/test/tools/AuthenticatorGenerator.java#L19     You can use a FormClient or IndirectBasicAuthClient to receive login/pwd credentials and validate them using the LdapAuthenticator (https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/wiki/Clients)

Comment: Can we use `play-pac4j` only for authorization without the need of binding a `SessionStore`? Where can I see an example? I'm trying it but I can get rid of the ones like `SessionStore` or `PlayCacheSessionStore`. What I'm trying to accomplish is what @jleleu has described: get the roles from the attributes of the user profile and add a `rolesRequired` attribute in the `@RequiresAuthentication`.